# How to change text of a DataGridColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumnheader

I have the following text column defined, and I want to programmatically replace the text in the 3 text blocks.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    x:Uid="Expiration_DataGridTextColumn"
    Binding="{Binding Expiration}">
    <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource ThreeLineColumnHeaderStyle}">
            <Setter
                Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Uid="Expiration_Header_Line1"
                                Text=""
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Uid="Expiration_Header_Line2"
                                Text="Expriation"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Uid="Expiration_Header_Line3"
                                Text=""
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind that text to any of your VM properties using Relative source binding.

You should override the HeaderTemplate rather than style,

```
<DataGridTextColumn
x:Uid="Expiration_DataGridTextColumn"
Binding="{Binding Expiration}">
                <DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="YourColumnName" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without binding?  I tried adding Name properties to those TextBlocks, but couldn't figure out how to find them.